# Find list of words(comma separated number) that are present in text based column in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am using php/mysql.
I am storing comma separated 6 digit numbers in text based column of table in database.

I want to get the  method to  find which numbers  in given range are present  in my database.

My table  looks like :

```
 |id|date|commaSeperatedList|
```

Now as input to sql I want to give a range of number (e.g 234101-234200).

Therefore I am expecting output to be in form of :

```
  |id|date|number|
```

So, far the solution I have worked on is : Use of PHP's range function.

Using that I created a string based Long Where Clause.

```
     foreach( $words as $word) {
      $word=str_pad($word, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
     $whereClause .= ' commaSeperatedList LIKE "%' . $word . '%" OR';
    }
```

Problem with it is that : I dont get to know exactly which were the numbers that were found common .

e.g  lets say List has :
109001,234122,234123,345650

I am giving the range (234101-234200)

The above statement finds all rows that contain any number in provided range . However I also want to know which exact numbers were matched. In my provided example these numbers are : 234122,234123

So, expected output should be :

```
   |1|date|234122|
   |1|date|234123|
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: _I store my data the totally wrong way, and now I'm having problems using it. It's complicated/difficult/too slow/doesn't work right! Can someone help?_ The answer is Yes - fix your data so it's stored properly to begin with, and all those problems using it go away. You don't have to optimize difficult things when they're not difficult in the first place

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Well , read above comments .. I would suggest that in your for loop create a temp array then match your string from database(using explode) , if data matches put it in temp array . When the loop is finished access the temp array from outside , you'll get what you need

Comment: Well, we have *normalized* data, and we have *denormalized* data. Now, it looks like we might have *abnormalized* data. :-)

Comment: This is tagged with mysql, sql, etc. but this has absolutely NOTHING to do with relational data.

Comment: @Stawberry : MYSQL is a a relational database and I am looking for some   syntactical MAGIC ( Obv its a magic for me, it will resolve my issue. Ha) in mysql that I am not aware of.  So, Both technically and literally, it is tagged under right category

Comment: @O.Jones ,  (Thanks for your input) Yup : I am already looking into  normalization . However , the issue with it is that : comma seperated numbers are way way way too much. Wouldn't that affect from memory(space) point of view?

Comment: @e4c5  (Thanks for your input) Yup : I am already looking into normalization . However , the issue with it is that : comma seperated numbers are way way way too much. Wouldn't that affect from memory(space) point of view?

Comment: @Vikrant, thats what I am doing now :   Problem with it is that , I cant exactly get which number out of range , were in list . I want  that number is my query to be specific.

Comment: @O.Jones : I cant deny the fact !!

Comment: @jarlh , Noted !, I am into converting db asap.(if its possible)(Data is scraped)

I saw something like  FULLMATCHTEXT (Match) syntax in mysql . Can't that help me?

Comment: @e4c5 .  Can you ^^ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually had to store data by normalization.
There are queries(Full Text Match) that were doing the work but not  only they were complex but slow as well.

As for me , Its always better to store data properly in normalized format. (Its not  a space/time tradeOFF).

For others in similar situation . Do some extra work on data and store it properly.
Thanks everyone for valuable answers !

Answer (score -1):

**Try This Code May Help You to find between range**

```
<?php
$list = "109001,234122,234123,345650";
$from = "234101";
$to = "234200";
$list = explode(",",$list);
foreach($list as $val)
{
if($val > $from && $val < $to)
{
    echo $val."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: The list is way too long . As for my estimate : it has more than 1000 numbers in it.

and a list is only 1 row (as per my schema).
So, it takes way too long. and still doesnt perfectly works